# paypal [Error: ACK Failure: Security header is not valid]

Tags: node.js, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I want to integrate the paypal in-context checkout experience but am having an error it appears like it has to do with my credentials. I double checked everything, but still cannot resolve the problem.

In my index.html file:

```
<form id="myContainer" action='/checkout' METHOD='POST'></form>
   <script>
    window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
    console.log('paypalCheckoutReady');
    paypal.checkout.setup('K9FXC5VWR963Q', {
                          environment: 'sandbox',
                          container: 'myContainer'
      });

    };
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

Then in my server.js file I have all my configurations as follows:

```
var paypal = require('paypal-express-checkout').init('username', 'password', 'signature', 'return url', 'cancel url', [debug]);
```

When I google the problem the most common solution is to make sure my username, password and signature are correct. I've done this but still cannot connect to the API. My terminal gives me this error:

```
{ TIMESTAMP: '2016-03-12T20:30:06Z',
CORRELATIONID: 'e1fda77960187',
ACK: 'Failure',
VERSION: '52.0',
BUILD: '18316154',
L_ERRORCODE0: '10002',
L_SHORTMESSAGE0: 'Security error',
L_LONGMESSAGE0: 'Security header is not valid',
L_SEVERITYCODE0: 'Error' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 10002 error indicates API credential not correct.

If you want to test sandbox APIs, please get API credential from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run after login by sandbox account.

If you want to call live APIs, please get API credentials from https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run after login.

Please make sure you didn't mix sandbox and live environment in the code. Thanks !